# Is it possible to strike the title shown in the title bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, title

Is it possible to strike the title

```
<title><s>My Title</s></title>
```

like this, so that the titlebar will show <s>My Title</s>?
Or is there a way to solve this with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Unicode combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) to add them. It will depend heavily on the font the OS/browser is using in the title bar on how it looks though.

```
function strike(text) {
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        output += '\u0336' + text[i];
    }
    return output;
}

function strikeTitle() {
   document.title = strike(document.title);
}
```

EDIT: Personally I like \u0337 the best.

Answer (score 19):

From [MDN on the `<title>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/title):

> The HTML Title Element defines the title of the document,
>   shown in a browser's title bar or on the page's tab. *It can only contain text and any contained tags are not interpreted.*

So no, it cannot be done like that.

**Update:**

Other answers suggest using various combinations of unicode characters to accomplish a strike through, and even though that might be possible and could yield a decent result, I believe it comes with a large drawback.

I'm not an expert in SEO in any way, but from what I know, and according to Googles [Search Engine Optimization Starters Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/sv//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) the `<title>` is of great importance when it comes to search engine optimization. Their guide suggest that **you should avoid**:

- Choosing a title that has no relation to the content on the page
- Using default or vague titles like "Untitled" or "New Page 1"

My interpretation would be that using obscure characters in your title would be a direct violation of that, so based on that I would strongly suggest that you avoid it.

Comment: The quoted text does not rule out the possibility of CSS being able to style the title, which was also asked about in the question; that text only says inline HTML won’t work. To test whether CSS works, I made a JS Bin with the CSS `title { text-decoration: line-through; }`. The [result, viewed full-page](http://jsbin.com/ucihib/2), shows that CSS does not work either ([source code](http://jsbin.com/ucihib/2/edit)).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Your right, that quote doesn't rule out CSS, but as you've proven your self, CSS cannot be applied to the title element. I tried to find a good reference to rule out CSS as well, but didn't find one immediately, and unfortunately I couldn't spend more time looking for one. Your example is a good proof to rule it out as well though.

Comment: I've added another answer that will do what you're asking using JavaScript.

Answer (score 13):

This **is possible** by using characters that have a strike built into them.  But this is the only way.  Using HTML markup or CSS will not yield the result you want.

Example using this: http://blog.imthy.com/2008/06/strikethrough-strikethrough-text.html

Comment: Correct, though quick testing shows that the strikethrough doesn't look great in the title bar, but this would be the only way.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Strikethrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Computer_methods) identifies the exact Unicode characters that can produce a strikethrough. The best character for this case is `U+0336 COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY`, which looks like this: “A̶B̶C̶D̶ ̶e̶f̶g̶h̶i̶”. Warning: in some fonts, that character fails to look like a strikethrough with successive letters of varying heights.

Comment: Yes, but if someone REALLY needs to have a strikethrough in their title, this is as close as they are going to get.

Comment: I believe the title element is quite relevant to search engines and SEO. Don't know how this will affect that, but my guess is that it won't be optimal in that sense.

Comment: You are correct.  for example, this search on google does not have the striked work in bold even though it was one of the search terms.  it should be the second result: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&spell=1&q=strikethrough+generator&sa=X&ei=XiqQUPr9HpKC8QSmwYCABw&ved=0CBsQvwUoAA&bpcl=36601534&pws=0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=2d96ede210ccce61&biw=1532&bih=878  but like i said, this is for someone who really needs this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

No, no browser known to me supports HTML rendering directly in the title bar, just the plaintext within the `<title>` tag will be displayed. The most you could hope to do is use some obscure characters where the line is part of each char - something very specific and something I care not to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the rendering of the `title` element content in the title bar, if it is displayed there. This does not depend on specifications but on implementations: browsers use their own routines to display the title, and HTML markup or CSS settings do not affect this.

Nothing prevents us from styling the `title` element as such, e.g.

```
title { text-decoration:line-through; }
```

but this has by default no visible effect, since the element is not part of the displayed document content. Adding

```
head, title { display: block; }
```

makes it visible, and you can see (in modern browsers) the content as overstruck on the page. But this does not affect the title bar (and isn’t particularly useful).

Using special characters in the element content, you can create overstriking as shown in other answers. This will however create a considerable risk of messing things up, because the routines that browsers use to display title bars often use a limited character repertoire, showing unsupported characters e.g. as small boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. The 'title' tag does not allow for any kind of formatting in its contents.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible, you can not control the `<title>` tag of a browsers window title with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Browser allows customization of the title of the document via two options

1. Fav icon 2. Title

Any customization with tags or css wil be ignored and only text and fav icon will be displayed on the title.

so if you want to play around title, you can still do with javascript, you can create animations that might work for you.