# Format Blog Title Using R Markdown and Hugo

Tags: css, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am using Hugo and Blogdown to create a blog as instructed [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/). The title of the blog is identified at the top of the post similar to this:

```
---
title: One Two Three
author: First Last
date: '2019-03-20'
```

When I inspect (Chrome) the title I see

```
<h1> One Two Three </h1>.
```

How do I apply a strikethrough font to just the word "Two" in the title?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blogdown, but if it uses R Markdown then maybe `One ~~Two~~ Three` would work. See [R Markdown - Authoring Basics - Miscellaneous](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_basics.html#miscellaneous).

Comment: Yes, the body of the blog post uses R Markdown so your solution works there. However, in the title section the title becomes, "One ~~Two~~ Three".

Comment: I do not think it is possible. This has to do with the template. The text is passed along as the `<title>` element : https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/280

Comment: I see. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

By default front matter parameters don't process markdown. But you can add [markdownify](https://gohugo.io/functions/markdownify/) to the template to force markdown processing:

```
{{ .Title | markdownify }}
```

If you use the same .Title parameter also for unformatted text in for example the [title tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142639/is-it-possible-to-strike-the-title-shown-in-the-title-bar) you can use [planify](https://gohugo.io/functions/plainify/) to strip the html codes away again:

```
{{ .Title | markdownify | plainify }}
```